# Powershell - CSV to a variable or list

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to get a list from the register of a csv, with Powershell.

**Script:**
$product = Import-Csv -Path $Path
$product

GA321
GA300

foreach($code in $product){Write-Host $codcom}

**Result:**
@{HEADER=GA321}
@{HEADER=GA300}

**What I expected:**
GA321
GA300

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the raw value stored in a property on one or more objects, use `ForEach-Object -MemberName`:

```
$rawValues = $product |ForEach-Object HEADER
```